# Simple jQuery plugin - reference error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing simple jQuery plugin and it should search all `.camp_row` on the page and everywhere when it find `.log.active`, it should change its border.

```
$.fn.filtruj = function(){
    $(this).on('click', function(){
        var that = $(this);
        $('.camp_row').each(function(){
            $(this).find(that).css('border','10px solid orange');
        }); 
    })
}

$('.log.active').filtruj();
```

The problem is, it wor on only one result. I think that's because "that" refer to a specific `.log.active'` but no all `.log.active`.

Comment: `that` resembles only one element. You set the css for `that` at least `n` times, where `n` is the number of `.camp_row` elements. That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, you should pass the selector in constructor, then:

```
$.fn.filtruj = function(selector){

  $(this).on('click', function(){
    var that = $(this);

    $('.camp_row').each(function(){
        $(this).find(selector).css('border','10px solid orange');
    }); 
  })
}

$('.log.active').filtruj('.log.active');
```

Comment: Great, it works. But first and second "log.active" always will be the same. Any option to avoid repeat this ?

Comment: unfortunately no… there was a deprecated property `selector` but it's removed. The documentation propose exactly this solution. http://api.jquery.com/selector/